# Yet another jQuery noConflict()

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery and $ now point to 1.10.2 -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery and $ now point to 1.11.0 -->
<script>
    $11 = $.noConflict();
    // $11 now points to 1.11.0
    // $ still points to 1.10.2
</script>

<!-- SB Admin Scripts -->
<script src="js/sb-admin.js"></script>

<!-- carouFredSel -->
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/carouFredSel-hookup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have problems getting this right.

The script **sb-admin.js** doesn't work together with the **carouFredSel.js** on the same page. The code above shows my attempt to use 2 different jQuery libraries and 2 different variables($ and $11), each of them pointing to one of the libraries.

In the script **sb-admin.js** I only use the variable **$11** and in **jquery.carouFredSel.js** and **carouFredSel-hookup.js** only the variable **§**.

At the moment none of the functions seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind me asking why you need to do this?

Comment: Do something like `console.assert($11.fn.jquery === "1.11.0")` indide `sb-admin.js`. Of course, remove it before deploying to production.

Comment: When you say that the functions doesn't seem to work, what do you mean specifically? What happens when you try the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: How do you know different jQuery versions will help?

Comment: 2 different jQuery versions to make sure $ and §11 do not use the same value and each of them can be used for a different function.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

You didn't provide the `true` argument. Change it to:

```
<script>
    $11 = $.noConflict(true);
    // $11 now points to 1.11.0
    // $ still points to 1.10.2
</script>
```

I have no idea whether this will solve the overall problem of conflicts between the two other libraries. It seems unlikely that it's because they require different versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I did try you recommendation and set the noConflict to (true), 
but it did not help whatsoever.

In the meantime I found a workaround but unfortunately I can't tell why it works now.
I am using another function for about the same menu and this one apparently doesn't conflict with my carousel.

This is the script that conflicted with the carouFredSel script was the menu from here:
http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-v2/

And this is the other menu script that works fine with carouFredSel is this:
http://demo.onokumus.com/metisMenu/